# Creating a data partition using caret and data.table

Tags: r, data.table, r-caret

I have a data.table in R which I want to use with caret package

```
set.seed(42)
trainingRows<-createDataPartition(DT$variable, p=0.75, list=FALSE)
head(trainingRows) # view the samples of row numbers
```

However, I am not able to select the rows with data.table. Instead I had to convert to a data.frame

```
DT_df <-as.data.frame(DT)
DT_train<-DT_df[trainingRows,]
dim(DT_train)
```

the data.table alternative

```
DT_train <- DT[.(trainingRows),] requires the keys to be set.
```

Any better option other than converting to data.frame?

Comment: That doesn't need the keys to be set.  How come you reached that conclusion?

Answer (score 7):

Roll you own

```
inTrain <- sample(MyDT[, .I], floor(MyDT[, .N] * .75))
Train <- MyDT[inTrain]
Test <- MyDT[-inTrain]
```

Or with Caret function you can just wrap `trainingRows` with a c().

```
 trainingRows<-createDataPartition(DT$variable, p=0.75, list=FALSE)
 Train <- DT[c(trainingRows)]
 Test <- DT[c(-trainingRows)]
```

===

Edit by Matt
Was going to add a comment, but too long.

I've seen `sample(.I,...)` being used quite a bit recently.  This is inefficient because it has to create the (potentially very long) `.I` vector which is just `1:nrow(DT)`. This is such a common case that R's `sample()` doesn't need you to pass that vector. Just pass the length. `sample(nrow(DT))` already returns exactly the same result without having to create `.I`.  See `?sample`.

Also, it's better to avoid variable name repetition wherever possible. More background [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10758086/403310).

So instead of :

```
inTrain <- sample(MyDT[, .I], floor(MyDT[, .N] * .75))
```

I'd do :

```
inTrain <- MyDT[,sample(.N, floor(.N*.75))]
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that `createDataPartition` produces integer vector with two dimensions where the second could be losslessly dropped.
You can simply reduce dimension of `trainingRows` using below:

```
DT[trainingRows[,1]]
```

The `c()` function from Bruce Pucci's answer will reduce dimension too.

This minor difference vs. data.frame was spotted long time ago and recently I've made PR [#1275](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/1275) to fill that gap.

Comment: awesome. Thanks jangorecki